# loop two arrays from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```js
$.each([data.bahan,data.detail], function (i, value) {
   $("select.bahan_asli").clone().insertAfter("#bahan:last").val(value[0].id_bahan).append("<input type='hidden' value='" + value[1].id_detail + "'>");  
});
```

The Json code :

```
{
    "bahan": [{
        "id_bahan": "4",
        "nm_jenis": "katun"
    }, {
        "id_bahan": "1",
        "nm_jenis": "katun"
    }],
    "detail": [{
        "id_detail": "5",
        "id_model": "3"
    }, {
        "id_detail": "6",
        "id_model": "3"
    }]
}
```

I tried this code. This json from my php script (create json by `array to json`). What's wrong with this code? How to call `value[0].id_bahan` and `value[1].id_detail`?

Answer (score 0):

In this case `each` is not working for what you want. I would go with a `for` loop, when `bahan` and `detail` are always the same length.

```
for( var i = 0; i < data.bahan.length; i++ ) {
    $("select.bahan_asli").clone()
                          .insertAfter("#bahan:last")
                          .val(data.bahan[i].id_bahan)
                          .append("<input type='hidden' value='" + data.detail[i].id_detail + "'>");
}
```

You can use `each` in a bit other way for it too, if you want:

```
$.each(data.bahan, function(i, bahan) {
    $("select.bahan_asli").clone()
                          .insertAfter("#bahan:last")
                          .val(bahan.id_bahan)
                          .append("<input type='hidden' value='" + data.detail[i].id_detail + "'>");
})
```

[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/gec5oj8b/1/)